# How to draw line in Silverlight Specifying Height?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I am trying to draw line in Silverlight Specifying Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top, Width, Height properties.  But its not getting displayed. What am I missing here ?  Iam trying to draw line without specifying the coordinates.

```
  Point pt1 = new Point();
            pt1.X = 50;
            pt1.Y = 50;

            Line l = new Line();
            l.Height = 5;
            l.Width = 5;
            l.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, pt1.Y);
            l.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, pt1.X);

  this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(l);
```

Thanks

Comment: Is "Width" supposed to indicate stroke size (e.g., line thickness) or are you trying to draw a diagonal line from {50, 50} to {55, 55}?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you're setting the canvas attached properties to the line before it's on the canvas? But it also seems like you're not specifying enough data for the line property?

Comment: @ Chris.. Thanks.Iam not trying to draw a Diagonal Line. "Width" supposed to indicate stroke size

Comment: Oh, you just want a vertical line? Why not use a border of some sort? Lines are intended to be used for diagonal lines?

Comment: @McKay: Lines can be used for whatever they want them to be used. What's wrong with a vertical line? What has an undefined slope ever done to you, huh!? :)

Comment: Oh, sure, lines can be horizontal, vertical, but those are the degenerate case. In which case, you  might want a simpler construct than line. If the app is heavily using a canvas already, then line might be a good shot, but a vertical line smells a little funny.

Comment: I completely disagree. Horizontal and vertical lines are just as valid as diagonal ones and don't smell on their own. Users should use `Line` objects where they make sense. If you wanted to create a `Border` object, then it should be a _border_ for some UI control. If you wanted to draw several lines to depict something made out of lines, then you should use a `Line`. If Ananth is using the `Line` object to act as a visual border for a UI control, then I agree, that's a smell and they _should_ use a `Border` _if possible_.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, lines have this format:

`<Line X1="50" Y1="50" X2="200" Y2="200" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="4" />`

Copied from http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/line-in-wpf/

```
Line redLine = new Line();
redLine.X1 = 50;
redLine.Y1 = 50;
redLine.X2 = 200;
redLine.Y2 = 200;

// Create a red Brush
SolidColorBrush redBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
redBrush.Color = Colors.Red;

// Set Line's width and color
redLine.StrokeThickness = 4;
redLine.Stroke = redBrush;

// Add line to the Grid.
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(redLine);
```

Comment: Thanks McKay. I was trying to draw line without specifying the X,Y Coorniates

Comment: But what does that even mean? How do you want to specify the line. Lines don't *have* height. I.e. Unless height or width is zero, there are two such lines that have the same height and width. One from the top left to bottom right of the bounding box, and one from the bottom left to the top right of the bounding box.

Comment: @McKay: I'm thinking they want to specify the origin point of the line and a relative offset for the end point rather than specifying two absolute points.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, you *must* specify `X1`, `X2`, `Y1`, `Y2`. But you can create helper methods to help you with this:

```
public Line CreateVerticalLine(Point startPoint, double height, double thickness)
{
    Line line = new Line();

    line.X1 = startPoint.X;
    line.Y1 = startPoint.Y;
    line.X2 = startPoint.X;
    line.Y2 = startPoint.Y + height;

    line.StrokeThickness = thickness;

    return line;
}
```

If you had your heart set on using the `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` properties, you can draw a line from its origin out:

```
public Line CreateVerticalLine(Point startPoint, double height, double thickness)
{
    Line line = new Line();

    //technically, you don't need to specify 0 for these, but I'll leave them
    //here to be explicit about what's going on
    line.X1 = 0;
    line.Y1 = 0;
    line.X2 = 0;
    line.Y2 = height;

    Canvas.SetTop(line, startPoint.Y);
    Canvas.SetLeft(line, startPoint.X);

    line.StrokeThickness = thickness;

    return line;
}
```

Note, you may want to favour the `Canvas.SetTop` and `Canvas.SetLeft` convenience methods as they will be type-safe and perform implicit type conversions for you.

Also note that you may want to reconsider this. By leveraging `Canvas.Top/Left` your line won't paint properly when set inside a `Grid`, `StackPanel`, or other containers. You could leverage its `Margin` instead and I think that will help. But unless there's a *specific* reason you *need* to use the Canvas positioning, I would suggest you stick with the first method and have the two coordinates explicitly specified.

Comment: The reason why this doesn't work, is that how would you draw a line from top right to bottom left? That would require a negative width (or negative height), and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @McKay: Not sure if I follow. I have updated my answer so I'm not sure if your question is applicable or not. I'm not leverage `Line.Width` or `Line.Height`.

Comment: @McKay: Ananth indicated that these are vertical lines. If they want diagonal lines, then its trivial to add an additional parameter and update the construction logic.

Comment: But then if you kept adding additional parameters in such a fashion, it would end up being more complicated than the line class already is: `CreateDiagonalLine(Point start, double height, double width, bool startTopLeft)`

Comment: @McKay: I wouldn't have the signature like that. I'd have `CreateLine(Point start, double horizontalOffset, double verticalOffset, double thickness)` or combine the offsets into a single `Point offset` parameter. I'm all in favour of writing methods to do things for you that the existing API cannot or to reduce code duplication. For example, there's no built-in mechanism (at least that I know of) to define a `Line` object based on a start point and a relative offset. If defining your lines based on such inputs _makes sense_ for what your application design is, why not do that?

Comment: Oh, yes, defining in terms of *offset* makes tons of sense. Defining lines in terms of *height* and *width* doesn't.